# how to load injection lib in mac applications at application start?

Tags: objective-c, macos, hook, code-injection, simbl

I have a dynamic library, I intent to inject in running application & newly launched applications.

I can inject it in running applications with the help of a process running with root user permissions.

Now I am trying that library should get loaded as soon as application is launched. I know one such library capable of doing this called, application enhancer. I am looking for similar behavior.

Does anyone has an Idea how can this be achieved?

Comment: Primarily MacOS. But I have ifdef for iphone processor too. Just need to test it.

Comment: Can SIMBL plugin be of help to you?

Comment: I have a plugin. But I cannot find proper references to enable me load the plugin in application when it starts. SIMBL can be very helpful if it can give me Idea on how to load plugin in application when it is about to launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [SIMBL agent code](http://code.google.com/p/simbl/source/browse/#hg/SIMBL%20Agent%253Fstate%253Dclosed). It adds a observer to application launch notification and then injects. You can follow the same approach.